# Parenthesis around route path

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I found this piece of code in a project using kraken and express

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('(/)', .....);
    router.get('(/nfc/read)', .....);
}
```

and I don't get why there are parenthesis around the routes paths.

Does it change something ? I can't find anything about it on the documentation of express and kraken.
In the rest of the whole project all the other routes are normal, without parenthesis.

Comment: auxiliary route

Comment: @epascarello could you be more specific and not just throwing 2 words ? The only thing I'm getting by searching 'auxiliary route' is about angular 2 and I never see the whole route path surrounded by parenthesis only the second part of the path and I still don't get what it changes from using just the path as is. Thank you

Comment: That is what it is called. I do not know much about it, hence why I only gave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between using and not using the parentheses is that when you use them then you will get the paths in `req.params`.

For example in this example:

```
let app = require('express')();
app.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params[0]);
});
app.listen(3333, () => console.log('http://localhost:3333/'));
```

what will be printed is `undefined`. But in this example:

```
let app = require('express')();
app.get('(/abc)', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params[0]);
});
app.listen(3333, () => console.log('http://localhost:3333/'));
```

what will be printed is `/abc`.

If there are more parentheses, there will be more elements in `req.params`. For example here:

```
let app = require('express')();
app.get('(/a)(bc)', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params[0]);
    console.log(req.params[1]);
});
app.listen(3333, () => console.log('http://localhost:3333/'));
```

the same `/abc` route would be matched but what would be printed is:

```
/a
bc
```

That is because the route is parsed as a regex and parentheses are capturing groups. See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Note that `req.params` is actually an object, not an array. This would return `false`:

```
console.log(Array.isArray(req.params));
```

It is just an object that happens to have numbers (actually strings like `"0"` and `"1"`) as its keys.